# Spring-boot. Создание таблиц по запросу

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Я работаю со Spring boot и JPA/Hibernate. 
У меня есть 2 типа таблиц:

1. ModelPool - список всех моделей, состоит из 2х полей: id и name
2. Model - описание модели.

Так как модель может хранить миллионы записей, характеризующие ее, и самих моделей может быть тысячи, то было принято решение, что для каждой модели необходимо создавать свою персональную таблицу.

**Вопрос. Как в Spring можно динамически создавать таблицы, давать им имена по некому алгоритму и помещать в application context?**

Уже достаточно долго бьюсь с этой задачей и не могу найти нормального решения.

Рассматриваю варианты реализации через @Query отправку прямого запроса на создание таблицы, но как ее инициализировать потом в application context?

Также копаю в сторону Entitymanagerfactory, но пока не могу найти нормального решения.

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: А чем hibernate-ddl не угодил?

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser так hibernate-ddl создает\обновляет предписанное количество таблиц и насколько я знаю работает только при старте приложения. Каким образом это может помочь в рантайме?

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser или имеется в виду org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport ? Тут я не очень понимаю, как новосозданную таблицу внести в apllication.context, то есть связать ее с бином в контейнере?

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser мои дальнейшие поиски показали, что в рантайме можно таблицы можно создавать при помощи LiquiBase или FlyWay библиотек... но все также пока не понимаю, как мне потом получить экземпляры моего класса Model, что осуществлять запись\чтение из БД

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser начал более детально копать в сторону DDL и нашел решение. Свое решение привожу в собственном ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Задача решена через реализацию DDL-script'а schema.sql и объявления соответствующего бина в applicationContext

```
 public DataSource createTable() {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");

        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));

        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator,dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Можно было просто подложить скрипт в class path и не писать этот конфиг

Comment: @VyacheslavGusser ну мне же все равно нужен метод, чтобы вызывать его по событию. Если я правильно понимаю, то просто положив скрипт в classpath, я его вызову только один раз при старте приложения.